# How do questions become HotNet questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that, every once in a while, a MESE question becomes a [HotNet Question](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), and then
the visits, comments, and answers skyrocket. This most recently happened (is happening) with
[How to answer questions about the purpose of learning math?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/19164/511).
This is great for MESE, draws in many new users.
But I am just wondering how this happens, because traffic on
MESE is generally ... tepid, and yet questions like that one suddenly take off.
Is there some other forum that links to MESE questions? Or is it the case that many users "lurk,"
checking MESE regularly but only participating when an enticing question
like the one cited is posted?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions

Comment: A more recent post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Thanks, Joel. But I don't see that those details explain why a low-traffic site like MESE attracts such interest.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake.  The first link I gave above was a formula for a "hot" question.  This link is a formula for a "hot network" question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions